# node.js request data event not firing on CORS ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

I'm trying to receive json from an ajax CORS call from a jquery process. But the `req.on('data' function(chunk) { })` event is not being called. I printed the json to the screen in the jquery process and it show's the JSON. In similar stack overflow question the person was doing routing before the data event and that's why it was not working. Or the person was making GET request which don't have a body and won't invoke the data event. Either way I am not sure why the data event is not firing.

```
 const https = require('https');

 var options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('domain.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('domain.crt')
 };

 https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
   var origin = (req.headers.origin || "*");

   if(req.method === "OPTIONS" && req.url === '/') {
     res.writeHead(204, "No Content", {
       "access-control-allow-origin": origin,
       "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
       "access-control-allow-headers": "content-type, accept",
       "access-control-max-age": 10,
       "content-length": 0
     });

    var requestBodyBuffer = [];

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      requestBodyBuffer.push(chunk);
      console.log('here'); //Not printing.
    })

    req.on('end', function() {
      var requestBody = requestBodyBuffer.join("");
      console.log(requestBody); // Empty
      var obj = JSON.parse(requestBody); // crashes here
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty('username') && obj.hasOwnProperty('password')) {
        console.log(obj.username);
        console.log(obj.password);
      }
    })
   } 
 }).listen(443);
```

Here is the jquery ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loginbtn').click(clickLogin);
  function clickLogin() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  if(password == '' || username == '') {
    $(".out").html("Empty username or password");
  } else {
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "https://localhost/",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password
        }),
        dataType: "text",
      })
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OPTIONS` request is separate from the `PUT` request, so your code should look something like this:

```
if (req.url === '/') {
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.writeHead(204, "No Content", ...);
    res.end();
  } else if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    var requestBodyBuffer = [];
    req.on('data', ...);
    req.on('end', ...);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the `else if (req.method === 'PUT')` is never called just the `if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {`

Comment: never mind I forgot `res.end()`, so now it works thanks.